# Rails Custom Validation error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

Without getting into all the javascript for a textfield, I'd like the following validation:

```
validates_length_of :brief_description,
  :maximum=>250, 
  :message => "Brief is #{self.brief_description.length} long (max is 250)"
```

But the self.brief_description reference in the message doesn't work. What's the best way to do this?

I tried 
    #{params[:brief_description].length}
as well, but the model doesn't know anything about params...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be wrong but I think you can try enclosing the string in single-quotes, and it might defer evaluating the string until runtime.

Short of that, you could write a custom validation (that doesn't use the validates_length_of macro) and do something like:

```
def validate_brief_description
  errors.add :brief_description, "Brief is #{brief_description.length} long (max is 250)" if brief_description.length > 250
end
```

Comment: The single quotes prevented the #{} from being evaluated, but the custom validation did the trick. Thank you!